# TypeORM - Requirement nullable option in relationship for @OneToMany side

Tags: node.js, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

In a project I need a nullable ManyToOne - OneToMany relation between two different entities. For now I solved it like this:

L1Log Entity (ManyToOne side)

```
@Entity()
export class L1Log extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  uuid: string

  @Column({ type: 'varchar', nullable: true })
  dimonaCancelUuid?: string

  @ManyToOne(() => DimonaCancel, dimonaCancel => dimonaCancel.l1Logs, { nullable: true })
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'dimonaCancelUuid' })
  dimonaCancel?: DimonaCancel
}
```

DimonaCancel Entity (OneToMany side)

```
@Entity()
export class DimonaCancel extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  uuid: string
  
  @OneToMany(() => L1Log, l1Log => l1Log.dimonaCancel, { nullable: true })
  l1Logs?: L1Log[]
}
```

My question is now whether or not the *{ nullable: true }* option is needed in the *@OneToMany* side of the relation because the *@OneToMany* will be an empty array when there are no relations setup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to set `nullable: true` on the One side of a OneToMany. If there are no `L1Log` items, then the query will return an empty array.

```
  @OneToMany(() => L1Log, l1Log => l1Log.dimonaCancel)
  l1Logs?: L1Log[]
```

On the Many side of the relation you should set `nullable: true`. Also best practice is to make the type of the property `DimonaCancel | null`. This is because it can return a null value and you can check this off if you use in your code.

```
  @ManyToOne(() => DimonaCancel, dimonaCancel => dimonaCancel.l1Logs, { nullable: true })
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'dimonaCancelUuid' })
  dimonaCancel?: DimonaCancel | null
```